# How do I run a cake file command from a cron file?

Tags: cron, coffeescript, cakefile

This is a bit of a mystery to me since you have to "be in" the folder of the Cakefile to run the cake command. I don't really know where cake its path from, but I've tried running this

```
cd /
PWD=/path/to/cake/file cake server
```

Still getting this error:

> Error: Cakefile not found in /

Would something like

```
cd /path/to/cake/file && cake server
```

Work in a cron file? Also could that pose a problem for the remaining cron jobs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `()` to make a subshell to run your command without affecting the rest:

```
(cd /path/to/cake/file && cake server)
```

Answer (score 1):

That's what I've done in the past for rake tasks, something like

```
cd /home/user/reports && /usr/local/bin/rake -f /home/user/code/stats/current/Rakefile report:generate_file
```

in a cron job to set the directory it's running out of. It doesn't cause any problems for any following cron jobs.

Answer (score 1):

It should work without any problems. Launching a subshell should not be necessary.

This works with cronie, but it should also work with dcron.